# How to import camanjs in ionic properly?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, camanjs

I tried to install camanjs on my ionic project.

I add to my app module :

```
import * as Caman from 'caman';
```

add it in provider :

```
@NgModule({

  providers: [
    Caman
  ]
})
```

on my `home.ts` :

```
import * as Caman from 'caman';

addBrightness(){
    Caman('#caman-image', function () {
      this.brightness(50).render();
    });
  }

getPicture(sourceType:PictureSourceType) {
    this.camera.getPicture({
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      allowEdit: true,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true
    }).then((imageData) => {

      this.selectedImage = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`;

    });
  }
```

and in my `home.html`:

```
<button ion-button full (click)="addBrightness()" [disabled]="!selectedImage">Add Brightness</button>

  <img [src]="selectedImage" #caman-image *ngIf="selectedImage">
```

and when I execute `ionic cordova emulate browser`, I got this error :

```
[09:51:52]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[09:51:52]  Error: ./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) 
            You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. (Source code omitted for this binary file) @ 
            ./node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js 3:17-56 @ ./node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js @ 
            ./node_modules/caman/dist/caman.full.js @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts 
Error: ./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js 3:17-56
 @ ./node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js
 @ ./node_modules/caman/dist/caman.full.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
```

I tried to search how to add caman properly to ionic , but I cant find it.

Please help me how to install and use caman in ionic or angular 4 please

Comment: Could you find solution for this?